# How do I run a foreach on a controller?

Tags: laravel, foreach, command

I want to send several emails, so that they are linked in a transition table, well all good, the problem is that when I use the command it only sends me an email and it is not repeated by each user as it should be because when using the foreach, I should send an email for each user that takes, at the same time review each query separately and if more than one user grabs me so I do not know why the command only sends me a single email. I hope you can help me and on the other hand I also want to use the email of the sis variable, but when using it within the 'mail' it tells me that said variable does not exist. Thanks for all beforehand.

my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\p;
use App\User;
use App\Pe;
use App\Mail\SendMailable;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class Alertc extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'S:AC';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send works';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {


           $hour= 14;
        $minute= 0;
        $second=0;
        $year= date("Y");
        $month= date("m");
        $day=date("d");
        $hourM=date("H");
        $dayy= now();

        $datelim=Carbon::Create($year,$month,$day,$hour,$minute,$second);
        $datedif=Carbon::Create($year,$month,$day,$hourM,$minute,$second);
        $dateen= $Datedif->addHour();
        $intervalH= $dayy->diffInHours($datelim);
        $intervalM= $dayy->diffInMinutes($dateen);

        $systems = User::where('codarea','>',0)->get();
        foreach ($systems as $system) {
            $sis = User::select('users.email', 'users.id', 'users.name', 'p.description', 'p.Dateen')
             ->join('pa', 'pa.user', '=', 'users.id')
             ->join('p', 'p.coddate','=','pa.env')
             ->where('p.read_at', '=', 0, 'AND')
             ->where('pa.user', '=', $system->id)
             ->where('p.Dateen', '>', $dayy)

              ->get();     


        $data = ['name' => "Alert" , 'periods' => $sis, 'Periodres' => $intervalH, 'Periodresm' => $intervalM,
        'Hactual' => $dayy, 'Hlimit' => $dateend];

    Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message) {

        $message ->from('coopme@gmail.com', 'ALERT');
        $message ->to('coopme@gmail.com')->subject('Alert');

    });
    return "La alert is finished";
    }
    }
}
```

my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Message Sent</title>
</head>
<body>
        <ul class="list-group">

            Good morning the next works is:
            @foreach($periods as $period)
            <li class="list-group-item">
                must send 
            <b>{{$period->description}}</b>
            @if($Hactual<$Hlimit)
            the limit is

            {{$Periodres}} Hours and

            {{$Periodresm}} Minutes.

           @elseif($Hactual>$Hlimit)
           is finished. 
           @endif


   </li>
@endforeach
<b><h6>Always with you</h6></b>
        </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my controller when i want use the sis variable inside the mail:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\p;
use App\User;
use App\Pe;
use App\Mail\SendMailable;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class Alertc extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'S:AC';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send works';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {


           $hour= 14;
        $minute= 0;
        $second=0;
        $year= date("Y");
        $month= date("m");
        $day=date("d");
        $hourM=date("H");
        $dayy= now();

        $datelim=Carbon::Create($year,$month,$day,$hour,$minute,$second);
        $datedif=Carbon::Create($year,$month,$day,$hourM,$minute,$second);
        $dateen= $Datedif->addHour();
        $intervalH= $dayy->diffInHours($datelim);
        $intervalM= $dayy->diffInMinutes($dateen);

        $systems = User::where('codarea','>',0)->get();
        foreach ($systems as $system) {
            $sis = User::select('users.email', 'users.id', 'users.name', 'p.description', 'p.Dateen')
             ->join('pa', 'pa.user', '=', 'users.id')
             ->join('p', 'p.coddate','=','pa.env')
             ->where('p.read_at', '=', 0, 'AND')
             ->where('pa.user', '=', $system->id)
             ->where('p.Dateen', '>', $dayy)

              ->get();     


        $data = ['name' => "Alert" , 'periods' => $sis, 'Periodres' => $intervalH, 'Periodresm' => $intervalM,
        'Hactual' => $dayy, 'Hlimit' => $dateend];

    Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message) {

        $message ->from('coopme@gmail.com', 'ALERT');
        $message ->to(sis->email)->subject('Alert');

    });
    return "La alert is finished";
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is:

```
$sis = User::select('users.email', 'users.id', 'users.name', 'p.description', 'p.Dateen')
             ->join('pa', 'pa.user', '=', 'users.id')
             ->join('p', 'p.coddate','=','pa.env')
             ->where('p.read_at', '=', 0, 'AND')
             ->where('pa.user', '=', $system->id)
             ->where('p.Dateen', '>', $dayy
             ->get();
```

It returns a collection. You need to foreach $sis and make an email array or use a method like first(), last()...

Something like this:

```
 $message ->to($sis->first()->email)->subject('Alert'); //To send to the first user of your query
```

Comment: Error: "Undefined variable: sis" To what can it be :(

Comment: You must explicitly inform that you want to use $sis inside anonymous functions in PHP, so, do this:  Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message) use ($sis) {

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the $ character in this section:

```
 $message ->to(sis->email)->subject('Alert');
```

Must be:

```
   $message ->to($sis->email)->subject('Alert');
```

Comment: $message ->to($sis->email)->subject('Alert'); I changed it and it appears to me " Undefined variable: sis"